# Symfony php templating

Tags: php, symfony, templating

I need some guidance in Symfony templating.
I just want to set default template for all views in one controller. Instead of extending the template in every view page. 
Please check the code how I am using right now.

```
//Controller
class HomeController extends Controller 
{
    public static $title="Customised Title";
    public function indexAction()
    {

          return $this->render('homeBundle:Home:index.html.php',array('name'=>'test','title'=>self::$title));
    }

    public function aboutAction()
    {
          //$this->view->extend('homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php');
          return $this->render('homeBundle:Home:about.html.php',array('name'=>'test','title'=>self::$title));
    }

}
```

Template

views/Templates/default.html.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php $view['slots']->output('title', isset($title)?$title:"Symfony Default Title") ?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
         <link href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/home/css/style.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/home/css/bootstrap-responsive.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php $view['slots']->output('_content') ?></body>
    </html>
```

Views
/views/Home/about.html.php

```
<?php $view->extend('homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php') ?>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sagittis vulputate urna.
```

/views/Home/index.html.php

```
<?php $view->extend('homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php') ?>
<?php
echo "hello ".$name;
?>
```

In the  above  views code we are extending homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php for each view. Is it possible to have it in controller(May be in constructor)?

Thank you Vbee for your help. Actually I am expecting something like view should not extend any more.
index.html.php should have only it's content. Like

```
<?php
        echo "hello ".$name;
?>
```

Instead of creating render method we can use static varialbe to achive same like you did.

```
class HomeController extends Controller 
{
    public static $title="Customised Title";
    public static $template="homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php";

    public function testAction()
    {

        return $this->render('homeBundle:Home:about.html.php',array('extend_view'=>self::$template,'name'=>'test','title'=>self::$title));
      }
}
```

But I want to render template  completely at controller side and in view  should have only action view content.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own render method in your controller:

```
<?php
//Controller
class HomeController extends Controller 
{
    public static $title="Customised Title";

    public function testAction()
    {
        return $this->renderWithExtend('homeBundle:Home:about.html.php', array('name' => 'test', 'title' => self::$title));
    }

    public function renderWithExtend($route, $params)
    {
        return $this->render($route, array_merge(array('extend_view', 'homeBundle:Templates:default.html.php'), $params));
    }
}
```

Then in you view:

```
// index.html.php
<?php $view->extend($extend_view) ?>
<?php
    echo "hello ".$name;
?>
```